# How to measure test execution duration with NewRelic Syntethics Scripts?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, newrelic, newrelic-synthetics

I'm using the newrelic synthetics scripted browser to check some user transaction flows for reliability and performance.

However the tracked duration is only about 8-10s which matches initial page load time, but not the async lazy loading of a large dataset (which is approx. 40s).

- *How can I make new relic synthetics scripted browser tests to show actual test execution duration and not only the duration of inital request?*
- *How can I track actual synthetics scripted browser test execution time and plot on a diagram with new relic?*

**The following I already tried and seems not to fix the issue:**

**Using a custom insight**

See [new relic docs for custom insights](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/synthetics/synthetic-monitoring/scripting-monitors/add-custom-attributes-synthetic-monitoring-data).

In script use:

```
var timeStart = Date.now();
var timeEnd = Date.now();
$util.insights.set('testDuration', (timeEnd - timeStart) );
```

with NRQL:

```
FROM SyntheticCheck SELECT numeric(custom.testDurration) WHERE numeric(custom.testDurration) > 0 SINCE 1 day ago
```

However in newrelic browser this data is shown as strings and thus cannot be plot on a chart as measurement.

- *What do I need to do to be able to make this a numeric measurement to be drawable as chart?*

**Timetracking with $har**

[New relic docs recommend using $har](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/synthetics/synthetic-monitoring/scripting-monitors/custom-timing-details/)

```
const testTimer = $har.addResource('Test Timer');
testTimer.startTimer();
await sleep(100);
testTimer.endTimer();
```

However $har is resulting in error: `Check failed with reference error. $har is not defined`;

- *How do I use $har correctly?*

** Checking KeySet, the custom properties show us stings**

As proposed on [new relic forum](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/response-time-log-table/155215) I checked the field type and it appears to be registered as string

NRQL `FROM SyntheticCheck SELECT keyset()` returns

```
[
  {
    "results": [
      {
        "stringKeys": [
          "custom.duration"
          "custom.testDuration",
```

Any other ideas how to achieve this?

Thx in advance, I really appreciate your expertise!

Answer (score 0):

You can log values with

```
$util.insights.set('testDuration', (timeEnd - timeStart) )
```

And when convert them within the query with

```
SELECT average(numeric(custom.testDuration)) FROM SyntheticCheck WHERE monitorName ='myMonitor' SINCE 7 days AGO TIMESERIES AUTO
```

However you cannot report this within the synthetics monitor and always need the query builder or a custom dashboard for analysis.

Would rather prefer a solution which properly reports within the synthetics monitor.